# http error 403.14- forbidden

Tags: iis-8

I  successfully hosted my test html page in **iis8**.

While I try to host the already created site I got the **http** error 403.14 forbidden. Even I set the default document as my starting html page which has the frame. The website has several folder inner folders. While I enable the  directory browsing  it will list the page. If I disable it shows 403.14 error.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

My Test page is like

```
<html>
<body>
Welcome
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share you folder structure? Is ur HTML page directly under your website? Or in a subfolder?

Comment: @Tamim Salem i have several folders and images with my web application folder.i enabled directory browsing it list the html pages and images.if i disable that property in iis8 i got 403.14 error. i set the default page instead showing the default page it list all pages

Comment: @TamimSalem i created my new website like this manner.  right click the sites. add new web site .set application pool as .net v4.5 classic and pyhsical path is c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MSCHN and set the ip address and port number. in MSCHN folder consist my web contents like index pages images and several inner folders. i set default document as index page. and the enable all the authentication. i just browse i got http 403.14 error. i enable the directory browsing  it list all the pages and images like link. i kindly request u to solve my issue. i am new to iss8.

Comment: @TamimSalem my html page is directly under folder.the linking pages only inside the subfolder. if i set the directory browsing is enabled shows the tree view . if i disabled the directory browsing then it shows an error

Comment: Did you try my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to reproduce it on my machine but couldn't reproduce it.

However, googling around around I found out that some people resolved the issue by running aspnet_regiis -i command, like so:

> 1. Run a command prompt as Administrator.
> 2. Copy and paste the following text “C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i”

The path may vary depending on your .NET Version.

Comment: This does not work in windows 8.1 only with dism.exe or with server manager gui

Comment: btw my solution was to right click an .aspx file and set it as startpage

Answer (score 0):

Just add  attribute: `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in `<modules>`, inside your Web.config.

**Final result:**

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```