# Random HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

Randomly while coding an ASP.NET MVC site I started getting HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden errors, and when going to specific pages ("/Views/Default/Index.cshtml"), I get

> The resource cannot be found.    Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Views/Default/Index.cshtml
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.32559

Which I guess means at least ASP.NET is being loaded, but why won't it recognize the page? I've tried so many reccomendations online, even went as far as removing the entry from IIS Express, then re-adding it through VS, copying the web.config from a working site to it, etc. Nothing seems to work - and it's only this one site. If I set directoryBrowse to true, I can get so far as a listing of all the pages & directories in my root. I can visit any of the directories **except** /Views/, which throws the same Resource can not be found error as above. I've also added directoryBrowse as true to the Web.config in /Views/, but to no avail.

Running the recommendation @ [http error 403.14- forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031653/http-error-403-14-forbidden) returns:

> Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.32559 Administration
>   utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. Start
>   installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.32559). This option is not supported on
>   this version of the operating system.  Administr ators should instead
>   install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Win dows
>   Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the
>   dism.e xe command line tool.  For more details please see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlin k/?LinkID=216771. Finished installing
>   ASP.NET (4.0.30319.32559).

I'm on Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2013 preview, and this has been working ever since about an hour ago, where it randomly started happening. I have a Global.asax file, and everything seems to be right (though obviously there's something off). I've getted the latest checkin to a new folder and ran from there, same problem. This is only one site, a site that was working perfectly just two hours ago. The only thing I can think of was that I was editing the routes when this happened, but I've changed the routes right back to what they were before and I'm having the same problem.

I'm at a complete loss as to what's happening, can anyone provide any kind of guidance? I'm willing to try/do/test whatever you need, I'd just like to figure out what's happening. Thank you so much, hopefully someone can figure out what's happening (and sorry about the lack of info on what I've tested and stuff - literally everything I saw in the past hour and a half of searching I've tried).

Answer (score 3):

I really, *really* hate it when that happens - after an hour or two of searching, I find the answer seconds after posting on SO -.-

Anyways, I had to add [HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631211/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-conte)

I'm still at a loss to explain how this randomly happened - I wasn't editing anything close to web.config when the error started - if anyone could provide some insight into that I'll accept their answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a year ago, but I just had this problem and I just found the reason for it.

I don't have an IIS Server running in my computer so I can`t change its configuration. When I debug my code, it seems Visual Studio 2013 runs a server of its own for debug purposes.

Anyway, I also started getting these random HTTP Error 403.14.

In the Solution Explorer Right Click on your project and choose Properties.
in the Properties Window, go to Web and you`ll see it is defaulted to Start Action at Current Page.

The reason debug sometimes work and sometimes does not is because sometimes you have the correct asp page selected at the time you press debug button, and sometimes you are at the wrong asp page. That`s all.